# Initializing multiple references with std::tie

Tags: c++, c++11

I'd like to have a neat way of initializing multiple references returned from a function via `std::tuple` using `std::tie` (or `std::forward_as_tuple`)—see toy code below.

```
#include <tuple>
#include <iostream>

class Foo
{
public:
    Foo () : m_memberInt(5), m_anotherMemberInt(7) {}

    void IncrementMembers() {++m_memberInt; ++m_anotherMemberInt;}

    std::tuple<int &, int &> GetMembers() {return std::tie(m_memberInt, m_anotherMemberInt);}

private:
    int m_memberInt;
    int m_anotherMemberInt;
};

int main()
{
    Foo foo;

    // Can't have dangling references.
    // int &x, &y;
    // std::tie(x, y) = foo.GetMembers();

    std::tuple<int &, int &> tmpTuple = foo.GetMembers();
    int &x = std::get<0>(tmpTuple);
    int &y = std::get<1>(tmpTuple);

    std::cout << x << " " << y << std::endl;

    foo.IncrementMembers();
    std::cout << x << " " << y << std::endl;

    return 0;
 }
```

The solution above works but having the temporary `std::tuple` and multiple `std::get`s is annoying and it would be great to be able to avoid this if possible (like when returning non-references).

The issue is that we can't have dangling references so can't initialize the variables beforehand. Is there some C++11/C++14 wizardry to allow me to initialize references as I call `std::tie`? Or is the above the only solution?

Comment: Would you be interested in some C++17 wizardry?

Comment: If that's the only way, then I'm all ears!

Comment: It looks like you want [Structured Bindings](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/c%2b%2b/487/how-to-return-several-values-from-a-function/3384/structured-bindings#t=201608231422577108315).  Unfortunately you have to wait for C++17.

Comment: Some variadic preprocessor magic could also work here ;)

Comment: @VittorioRomeo I double dog dare you.  And no using `boost`'s preprocessor library, self contained answer only!

Comment: @jaw: `auto [x, y] = foo.GetMembers();`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In C++17 Structured Bindings writes your code for you.

```
std::tuple<int &, int &> tmpTuple = foo.GetMembers();
int &x = std::get<0>(tmpTuple);
int &y = std::get<1>(tmpTuple);
```

is roughly the same as

```
auto&[x,y] = foo.GetMembers();
```

(I might have minor syntax errors in my C++17 code, I lack experience, but you get the idea.)

You can do something similar in C++14 with continuation passing style and an adapter:

```
template<class Tuple>
struct continue_t {
  Tuple&& tuple;
  using count = std::tuple_size<std::remove_reference_t<Tuple>>;
  using indexes = std::make_index_sequence<count{}>;

  template<std::size_t...Is>
  auto unpacker(std::index_sequence<Is...>) {
    return [&](auto&& f)->decltype(auto){
      using std::get; // ADL enabled
      return decltype(f)(f)( get<Is>(std::forward<Tuple>(tuple))... );
    };
  };
  template<class F>
  decltype(auto) operator->*( F&& f )&& {
    auto unpack = unpacker( indexes{} );
    return unpack( std::forward<F>(f) );
  }
};
template<class F>
continue_t<F> cps( F&& f ) {return {std::forward<F>(f)};}
```

which, modulo typoes, gives you:

```
cps(foo.GetMembers())
->*[&](int& x, int&y)
{
  std::cout << x << " " << y << std::endl;

  foo.IncrementMembers();
  std::cout << x << " " << y << std::endl;
};

return 0;
```

which is strange.  (Note that `cps` supports functions that return pairs or `std::array`s and anything "tuple-like").

There really isn't a better way to handle this, structured bindings where added to C++17 for a reason.

A horrible preprocessor hack could probably be written that looks like:

```
BIND_VARS( foo.GetMembers(), x, y );
```

but the volume of code would be large, no compiler I know of lets you debug the mess that would be generated, you get all the strange quirks that preprocessor and C++ intersection causes, etc.

Comment: I've read that whenever possible variables declared with structured bindings are aliases for the respective members, rather than actual variables, so maybe references aren't needed (e.g. `x` is actually `foo.m_memberInt`). Don't know if that made it into the final version and can't find where I read that.

Answer (score 3):

Self-contained preprocessor metaprogramming solution, as challenged by [Yakk](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1774667/yakk).

Code adapted from my own [vrm_pp](https://github.com/SuperV1234/vrm_pp/) lightweight preprocessor metaprogramming library.

Supports 8 tuple elements.

*(This is horrible. The awesome kind of horrible.)*

```
#include <tuple>
#include <iostream>
#include <cassert>
#include <type_traits>

#define __INC_0 1
#define __INC_1 2
#define __INC_2 3
#define __INC_3 4
#define __INC_4 5
#define __INC_5 6
#define __INC_6 7
#define __INC_7 8
#define __INC_8 9

#define __NSEQ( m1, m2, m3, m4, m5, m6, m7, mN, ...) mN
#define __RSEQ()    7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 0
#define __CSEQ()    1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0

#define __FOR_0(i, f, x)
#define __FOR_1(i, f, x, a0)          f(i, x, a0)
#define __FOR_2(i, f, x, a0, a1)      f(i, x, a0) __FOR_1(INC(i), f, x, a1)
#define __FOR_3(i, f, x, a0, a1, ...) f(i, x, a0) __FOR_2(INC(i), f, x, a1, __VA_ARGS__)
#define __FOR_4(i, f, x, a0, a1, ...) f(i, x, a0) __FOR_3(INC(i), f, x, a1, __VA_ARGS__)
#define __FOR_5(i, f, x, a0, a1, ...) f(i, x, a0) __FOR_4(INC(i), f, x, a1, __VA_ARGS__)
#define __FOR_6(i, f, x, a0, a1, ...) f(i, x, a0) __FOR_5(INC(i), f, x, a1, __VA_ARGS__)
#define __FOR_7(i, f, x, a0, a1, ...) f(i, x, a0) __FOR_6(INC(i), f, x, a1, __VA_ARGS__)
#define __FOR_8(i, f, x, a0, a1, ...) f(i, x, a0) __FOR_7(INC(i), f, x, a1, __VA_ARGS__)

#define __CAT_2(m0, m1) m0##m1
#define CAT_2(m0, m1) __CAT_2(m0, m1)

#define __INC(mX) __INC_##mX
#define INC(mX) __INC(mX)


#define __N_ARG(...) __NSEQ(__VA_ARGS__)

#define __ARGCOUNT(...) \
    __N_ARG(__VA_ARGS__, __RSEQ())

#define ARGCOUNT(...) __ARGCOUNT(__VA_ARGS__)


#define __FOR(f, x, ...) \
    CAT_2(__FOR_, ARGCOUNT(__VA_ARGS__))( \
        0, f, x, __VA_ARGS__)

#define FOR(...) __FOR(__VA_ARGS__)

#define REF_TIE_BODY(mIdx, x, mArg) \
    decltype(std::get<mIdx>(x)) mArg = std::get<mIdx>(x);

#define REF_TIE(tuple, ...) \
    FOR(REF_TIE_BODY, tuple, __VA_ARGS__)

int main()
{
    int a = 0, b = 1;
    std::tuple<int &, int &> tmpTuple{a, b};

    REF_TIE(tmpTuple, aref, bref);

    assert(a == aref);
    assert(b == bref);

    static_assert(std::is_same<decltype(aref), int&>{}, "");
    static_assert(std::is_same<decltype(bref), int&>{}, "");
}
```

*(See previous edits on this answer for a vrm_pp-compliant version.)*

Comment: What if my tuple is named `bob<hello, three, tokens>()`?  You aren't going to force me to use *extra brackets* are you?